# React hooks a functional update causes the eslint no-shadow error

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

I'm using React useEffect to update a state. Eslint warns I'm making no-shadow error. I think this is related to some eslint or eslint plugin settings because CRA doesn't cause the same error. How to fix it?

```
function Sample(props) {
  const { flag } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (flag) {
      setValue(value => value + 1);
    }
  }, [flag]);
}
```

Here, `setValue(value => value + 1);` the value causes no-shadow due to declared at the useState.

Answer (score 2):

eslint is correctly complaining because you've declared a `value` variable in your `useState` hook, but then you're re-declaring *another* variable called `value` in your `useEffect` hook.

The simplest fix is to not shadow the variable name by changing the variable in your `setValue` call -

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (flag) {
    setValue(prev => prev + 1);
  }
}, [flag]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found that removing 'airbnb' option from the extends of eslint can solve the issue.

Comment: @SungwooPark - yep that would probably work too but you're weakening the linter - the warning it's given you is valid and worth changing your code, otherwise it can lead to unintentional errors!